# yii hasone relation with condition

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2, relationship

I have a hasone relation in my code,

```
public function getDevice(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserDevice::className(),['user_id' => 'id'])->where(['is_latest'=>true]);
}
```

In my query, I am trying to fetch user details.

```
  $query = User::find();
  $query->joinWith('device')->all();
```

If i am using getDevice without where condition, I am getting all users. But if I add where condition inside getDevice, I am getting  users that have device details.
Is there anyway to list all users with the chceking.
That is I need to list all users, who has either details in device table or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this in my relation and it works.

```
public function getDevice(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserDeviceInfo::className(),['user_id' => 'id'])->orOnCondition(['is_latest' =>1]);
}
```